# Show the name and town of OOUR that employed at least two merchant passengers in the first two months of 1981

Tags: mysql, sql

Show the name and town of OOUR that employed at least two merchant passengers in the first two months of 1981.

OOUR
[image: OOUR]

RADNIK
[image: RADNIK]

```
SELECT naziv, grad
FROM OOUR o, RADNIK r
WHERE o.soour=r.sradnik
AND DATZAP = (month(FEB) OR month(JAN)
AND (count(trg_putnik) FROM RADNIK ) > 2
```

Comment: Please edit in the schema details instead of linking to images - you have also specified MySQL and Oracle - 2 different database systems, please choose just 1, or explicitly say if it needs to run on both platforms.

Comment: What is your question? Or is this just "please do my homework for me"?

Comment: i dont know where is problem in my code..

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: `... DATZAP IN (month(FEB), month(JAN)) ...`

Comment: Check out GROUP BY, and HAVING.

Answer (score 0):

You have compare o.sour with r.sour
Try with this

```
SELECT naziv, grad
FROM OOUR o, RADNIK r
WHERE o.soour=r.soour
AND DATZAP = (month(FEB) OR month(JAN)
AND (count(trg_putnik) FROM RADNIK ) > 2
```